# Sum values larger than the current value, by group

Tags: r

I have measured basal area of trees in different plots. Here's a small example with two plots with 4 trees each:

```
Plot    Tree    BasalArea
1         1         4
1         2         5
1         3         7
1         4         3
2         1         4
2         2         6
2         3         9
2         4         5
```

Within each plot, I want calculate the sum of basal area of the trees that have basal area larger than the focal tree.

For example, Tree 1 in Plot 1 has an area of 4. Within that plot there are 2 trees with an area larger than tree 1: Tree 2 and Tree 3 with area 5 and 7, respectively. So, "BA_Larger" for tree 1 is 5 + 7 = 12.

Tree 2 in the same plot has basal area = 5. Within plot 1 there is only one tree with a larger area than tree 2: tree 3 with area 7. Thus, "BA_Larger" for tree 2 is 7.

Finally, the data frame should be like this:

```
Plot    Tree    BasalArea   BA_Larger
1         1        4          12
1         2        5           7
1         3        7           0
1         4        3          16
2         1        4          20
2         2        6           9
2         3        9           0
2         4        5          15
```

The data set is very large. I have tried to calculate the "BA_Larger", without success. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(Plot) %>% 
  arrange(BasalArea, .by_group = T) %>% 
  mutate(res = sum(BasalArea) - cumsum(BasalArea)) %>% 
  arrange(Tree, .by_group = T) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 4
   Plot  Tree BasalArea   res
  <int> <int>     <int> <int>
1     1     1         4    12
2     1     2         5     7
3     1     3         7     0
4     1     4         3    16
5     2     1         4    20
6     2     2         6     9
7     2     3         9     0
8     2     4         5    15
```

Comment: Nice. I'm not sure if it gives the desired result in presence of duplicated values though; e.g. `x = c(1, 2, 2, 2)`; `sum(x) - cumsum(x)`. But perhaps that is not the case for OP. It should be fast though.

Comment: Same in `base`: `transform(d[order(d$Plot, d$BasalArea), ], a2 = ave(BasalArea, Plot, FUN = function(x) sum(x) - cumsum(x)))`

Comment: what answer should be in this case?

Comment: My guess: In `x`, there are no values that are larger than 2, so according to "_sum of basal area of the trees that have basal area larger than the focal tree_", I would expect the result to be `0` for all 2s. But we just have to let OP clarify if ties are an issue in the first place. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The `base` R solution with `ave()`:

```
within(df, BA_Larger <- ave(BasalArea, Plot, FUN = function(x) sapply(x, function(y) sum(x[x > y]))))
```

---

With a `tidyverse` style, you can also use `map_int()` or `map_dbl()` from `purrr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(Plot) %>%
  mutate(BA_Larger = map_int(BasalArea, ~ sum(BasalArea[BasalArea > .]))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

---

***Output***

```
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#    Plot  Tree BasalArea BA_Larger
#   <int> <int>     <int>     <int>
# 1     1     1         4        12
# 2     1     2         5         7
# 3     1     3         7         0
# 4     1     4         3        16
# 5     2     1         4        20
# 6     2     2         6         9
# 7     2     3         9         0
# 8     2     4         5        15
```

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(Plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Tree = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), BasalArea = c(4L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 9L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a non-equi join with `data.table`. Calculate sum for each match.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[ , ba2 := d[d, on = .(Plot, BasalArea > BasalArea), sum(x.BasalArea), by = .EACHI]$V1]

#    Plot Tree BasalArea ba2
# 1:    1    1         4  12
# 2:    1    2         5   7
# 3:    1    3         7  NA
# 4:    1    4         3  16
# 5:    2    1         4  20
# 6:    2    2         6   9
# 7:    2    3         9  NA
# 8:    2    4         5  15
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need a package to do this. Using `by` you may split the data on the `Plot` column, then compare the specific tree `i` to the other values in the split-subset and exclude `i` in the `sum`. Finally `unsplit` the result according to the `df1$Plot` column.

```
res <- unsplit(by(df1, df1$Plot, function(x) 
  transform(x, BA_Larger=sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) 
    sum(x[x[, 3] > x[i, 3], 3])))), df1$Plot)
res
#   Plot Tree BasalArea BA_Larger
# 1    1    1         4        12
# 2    1    2         5         7
# 3    1    3         7         0
# 4    1    4         3        16
# 5    2    1         4        20
# 6    2    2         6         9
# 7    2    3         9         0
# 8    2    4         5        15
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(Plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Tree = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), BasalArea = c(4L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 9L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```